# POST Request from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to POST with my chrome extension.
Here is the method I am using for it.

```
function uploadFile(url){
  var req = new XMLHTTPRequest();
  req.open("POST", "https://wepicit.s3.amazonaws.com/", true);
  var params = "key="+myKey
               "&acl="+"public-read"
               "&Content-Type="+"text/plain"
               "&AWSAccessKeyId"+tempKey
               "&file="+url+".txt"
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
  req.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
  req.send(params);
  req.onreadystatechange = function(){ 
        // If the request completed, close the extension popup
        if (req.readyState == 4)
            if (req.status == 200) console.log('success');
  };
}
```

The error that I am getting is that 'XMLHTTPRequest()' is not defined. Please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive.

Not `new XMLHTTPRequest()` but rather `new XMLHttpRequest()`.